# iterate through objects/variables Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, loops, variables, object

How can I iterate through objects/variables in Swift. Can I create an array or dictionary when I have objects attached so that I don't have to write code for each button. I'm a nubie so please speak to me like I'm four. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
...


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.button1.alpha = 0.0
    self.button2.alpha = 0.0
    self.button3.alpha = 0.0
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
    var arrayOfButtons = [UIButton]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    arrayOfButtons = [button1, button2, button3]
    for button in arrayOfButtons {
        button.alpha = 0.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add variable into an object name. For example: button/(count).alpha = 0.0

Comment: @codekid, I don't think you can add a variable like that once an object is created. But if you want to call a specific button, you could create a Dictionary `[String: UIButton]` instead of an array `["button1": button1, "button2": button2, "button3": button3]`. Then call `dictOfButtons["button/(count)"].alpha = 0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Tim's answer, you can also create buttons programmatically, and deal with them in your code!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
for i in 1...10 {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRectMake((CGFloat(i-1)*50), 0, 50, 50)
    button.targetForAction("buttonClick:", withSender: self)
    button.tag = i
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}
}


func buttonClick(sender:AnyObject) {
    let tag = sender.tag!
    //click logic here
}
```